# Importing a module to do file manipulation relative to the file that imported it

Tags: python, import, module, directory, path

I'm trying to build a function that will save a pandas `dataframe` to a csv and also save a copy of the python script that invoked it.

I want the function to get the location of the file that invoked it. 
So I created the following file:

functions.py:

```py
def full_save():
    filePath = os.path.abspath('')
    currentFileDir = os.path.join(filePath, os.path.basename(__file__))
    print(currentFileDir)
```

Imported and called the function from another file:

foo.py:

```py
from functions import *

full_save()
```

And I got the directory for `functions.py` instead of `foo.py`.

I want to get `"/somelocation/foo.py"`, but I'm getting `"/modulelocation/functions.py"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach back on the call-stack and access the caller's globals.

functions.py:

```
import sys

def full_save():
    namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # Caller's globals.
    print(f'namespace["__file__"]: {namespace["__file__"]!r}')
```

Comment: Sir, you're awesome.